# In angular, how to get both the selected text as well as value of the dropdown selected item?

Tags: angular, typescript

Does any body know, in angular, how to get both the selected text as well as value of the dropdown selected item ?

**Code**

```
                     <select
                        [(ngModel)]="model.country"
                        class="
                          form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid
                        "
                        name="country"
                        #cont
                        (change)="onCountrySelected(cont.value)"
                      >
                        <option
                          *ngFor="let country of countriesList"
                          value="{{ country.id }}"
                        >
                          {{ country.name }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
```

How can I get the text and value on executing the onCountrySelected() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of providing your own parameter to the function you can use the `$event` keyword to get the actual event data. like so:

```
(change)="onCountrySelected($event)"
```

To get the data you want just log the event in your ts and access the properties like so (I don't know the exact type from memory).

```
onCountrySelected(event: any) {  
  console.log(event); // look in the console to get the properties
  event.target.value // you can access them like that
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. For getting the selected text, I used event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text